# Mixing 2 video files, one with alpha channel (partially transparent)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing

I'm looking for an opensource solution to mix 2 mp4 files. First one on top of the second one. The first video is partially transparent.

What would be the best way to do this ? Is ffmpeg the solution ?

Could You provide some examples ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got any transparent movies to test. Did you try:

```
ffmpeg -i source1.mp4 -i source2.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay" -strict -2 output.mp4
```